# Is the word "connector" in meaningful for a software product

Tags: single-word-requests

We have a product that synchronizes data between an online-shop and a popular erp (enterprise resource planning) system. Now the question is, if the product name "System1Name System2Name Connector" actually makes sense in english?

I was wondering if there was another word that is probably a better fit for these kind of applications? Maybe "gateway" or "exchanger"?

Comment: Sure, it makes sense. Why can't you use System1Name-System2Name Synchronizer, though?

Comment: Oh, I can use that as well. Just wanted to make check what sounds more reasonable to native speakers. Thanks!

Comment: This seems off-topic here. Shouldn't you ask on  programmers.SE, where they would know about the intricate nuances of patterns and such? (or if not a 'pattern' then technically appropriate alternatives).

Comment: I don't think so because the ones that need to 'understand' the word are normal customers without technical knowledge. Therefore I think it is a more general question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A conjunction or preposition between the two system-names is needed to make the name grammatically sound; for example, both of "Facebook and Flickr Connector" and "Facebook to Flickr Connector" are correct and understandable.  "Facebook/Flickr Connector" also is a possibility.  [Note, company names randomly chosen.]

By contrast, "Facebook Flickr Connector" looks like two adjectives and a noun, that is, would represent a connector for the "Facebook version of Flickr", if there were such a thing.

Your alternate terms, *gateway* and *exchanger*, are reasonable alternatives to *connector*, except that  *connector* is a term frequently used in [enterprise application integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_EE_Connector_Architecture), so may be a good fit with your Enterprise Resource Planning to online shopping synchronizer.